# make div that contains an iframe dynamic?

Tags: iframe

I have a div container and in it is an iframe. The iframe's height is dynamic meaning it changes with the content. The problem is that the div container's height doesn't dynamically change with the iframe's height. How do I make the div container's height change dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If javascript is an option, you can try [this](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/).

Comment: I have disabled scrolling already with scrolling="no". So I have to find out the height of iframe instead of 'scrollHeight'. How would I do that? What should be the right term in place of 'scrollHeight'?

Comment: `f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + “px”;` is to set the height of the iFrame to it's content scrollHeight.